# Dockerized HAProxy and VIRTUAL_HOST for many sites

Tags: docker, docker-compose, haproxy

I have **many** docker-compose.yml files for different site and they are not linked to haproxy.

I want set environment VIRTUAL_HOST in each site, start **one** haproxy with links (?) and all sites must works.

The goal: If I want add new site, other sites will not restart. And all sites must be independents with own docker-compose file.

I do this with default network *bridge* and external_links ([try it](https://github.com/lomaster1/docker-external-haproxy)) and it's works.

I think it is not best way and also docker-compose scale automaticaly is not working.

Which is a best way for do that?

Comment: Why not user network overlay? That handle multi-host networking: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-overlay/. As for scaling, that looks like swarm.

Comment: You might want to check [Kontena](http://www.kontena.io) where this kind of loadbalancing is built-in. https://kontena.io/docs/using-kontena/loadbalancer